# scss code to ignore first child for & operator

Tags: sass

I used this scss (my version of scss)

```css
section[data-testid="title-cast"] {
    .ipc-media--avatar-circle,
    .ipc-avatar {
        &,
        .ipc-lockup-overlay,
        .ipc-lockup-overlay__screen {
            border-radius: 5px !important;
        }
    }
}
```

to get this css (expected output)

```css
section[data-testid="title-cast"] .ipc-media--avatar-circle,
section[data-testid="title-cast"] .ipc-avatar,
section[data-testid="title-cast"] .ipc-avatar .ipc-lockup-overlay,
section[data-testid="title-cast"] .ipc-avatar .ipc-lockup-overlay__screen {
    border-radius: 5px !important;
}
```

but got this css (got wrong output)

```css
section[data-testid=title-cast] .ipc-media--avatar-circle,
section[data-testid=title-cast] .ipc-media--avatar-circle .ipc-lockup-overlay,
section[data-testid=title-cast] .ipc-media--avatar-circle .ipc-lockup-overlay__screen,
section[data-testid=title-cast] .ipc-avatar,
section[data-testid=title-cast] .ipc-avatar .ipc-lockup-overlay,
section[data-testid=title-cast] .ipc-avatar .ipc-lockup-overlay__screen {
  border-radius: 5px !important;
}
```

how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`@extend`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend/) to get the expected output:

```scss
section[data-testid="title-cast"] {
  .ipc-media--avatar-circle {
    border-radius: 5px !important;
  };
    
  .ipc-avatar {
    &,
    .ipc-lockup-overlay,
    .ipc-lockup-overlay__screen {
      @extend .ipc-media--avatar-circle;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thx that worked